# Filter empty and/or null values with jq

Tags: json, null, jq, key-value, jsonlines

I have a file with jsonlines and would like to find empty values.

```
{"name": "Color TV", "price": "1200", "available": ""}
{"name": "DVD player", "price": "200", "color": null}
```

And would like to output empty and/or null values and their keys:

```
available: ""
color: null
```

I think it should be something like `cat myexample | jq '. | select(. == "")'`, but is not working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The tricky part here is emitting the keys without quotation marks in a way that the empty string is shown with quotation marks.  Here is one solution that works with jq's -r command-line option:

```
to_entries[]
| select(.value | . == null or . == "")
| if .value == "" then .value |= "\"\(.)\"" else . end
| "\(.key): \(.value)"
```

Once the given input has been modified in the obvious way to make it valid JSON, the output is exactly as specified.

Comment: Thanks! Corrected the input. I don't really understand the logic here. Can't we just filter keys with empty value? Why convert to_entries and then select entries and then... don't really know what happens there!

Comment: You might like to read the jq tutorial and the relevant sections of the jq manual -- see [tag:jq]

Comment: What these to_entries[] mean and how do you use this with jq ?

Comment: @VM47 - Please see the jq manual https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Answer (score 14):

Some people may find the following jq program more useful for identifying keys with null or empty string values:

```
with_entries(select(.value |.==null or . == ""))
```

With the sample input, this program would produce:

```
{"available":""}
{"color":null}
```

Adding further information, such as the input line or object number, would also make sense, e.g. perhaps:

```
with_entries(select(.value |.==null or . == ""))
| select(length>0)
| {n: input_line_number} + .
```

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at this snippet https://blog.nem.ec/code-snippets/jq-ignore-nulls/

```
jq -r '.firstName | select( . != null )' file.json
```

Comment: `jq -r '.firstName | select(.)' file.json`

Answer (score 2):

With a single `with_entries(if .value == null or .value == "" then empty else . end)` filter expression it's possible to filter out `null` and empty (`""`) values.

Without filtering:

```
echo '{"foo": null, "bar": ""}' | jq '.'
{
  "foo": null,
  "bar": ""
}
```

With filtering:

```
echo '{"foo": null, "bar": ""}' |  jq 'with_entries(if .value == null or .value == "" then empty else . end)'
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select(.)` to filter out the nulls