# optimize multiple sed commands in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I have a folder containing many text files with json content in it. With jq library, I am able extract the "commodities" array and write it to a file. The "commodities-output.txt"  is a temp file that contains brackets "[", "]" and "null" values apart from the string values in the array. I want to remove the square brackets, "null" value and get the unique string values in a text file. Is there a way to optimise the sed command so that I don't have to create temporary text files such as "commodities-output.txt" and only have one output file with all the string values I need that are uniq and sorted(optional to be sorted).

```
$F=foldername
for entry in $F*.json
do
  echo "processing $entry"
  jq '.[].commodities' $entry >> commodities-output.txt
done
sed '/[][]/d' commodities-output.txt | sed '/null/d' commodities-output.txt | sort commodities-output.txt | uniq >> commodities.txt

echo "processing complete!"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting output of bash for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612603/redirecting-output-of-bash-for-loop)

Comment: Or this? [Combining two `sed` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands)

Comment: A better fix altogether is to fix the `jq` filter so it doesn't output `null` or empty lists. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692037/filter-empty-and-or-null-values-with-jq

Comment: `sed cmd file | sed cmd file | ...` is nonsensical.  The first sed reads from the file, but its output is completely ignored as the 2nd sed also reads from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do all of this in `jq`.

```
files=( "$F"*.json )
echo "$0: processing ${files[0]}" >&2
jq '.[] | select(.commodities != [] and .commodities != null) | .commodities' "${files[0]}"
```

I refactored to use a Bash array to get the first of the matching files.

If for some reason you can't refactor your code to run entirely in `jq`, you definitely want to prefer pipes over temporary files.

```
for entry in "$F"*.json
do
  echo "$0: processing $entry" >&2
  jq '.[].commodities' "$entry"
  break
done |
sed -e '/[][]/d' -e '/null/d' |
sort -u > commodities.txt
```

Notice also how we take care to print the progress diagnostics to standard error (`>&2`) and include the name of the script in the diagnostic message. That way, when you have scripts running scripts running scripts, you can see which one wants your attention.

Also, [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: I went with the second pipe approach which seems to be easy to understand, fits to my purpose and gives the expected result.

Comment: You can easily use the loop from the second with the `jq` expression from the first if you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

```
...
# write to target file, no temp needed
jq '.[].commodities' $entry >> commodities.txt
...
# You can read it with first sed command and pipe the output to next sed command (it reads stdin) and to the next commands
# Also, sort has -u flag that do the same as uniq, so you don't need a separate command
# At the end rewrite your target file with the result from sort
sed '/[][]/d' commodities.txt | sed '/null/d' | sort -u > commodities.txt
```

Comment: Thanks!! this is something I am looking for. Since the files are too many, it's taking time. I will test it with these commands and mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I guess there is some error, the last file comes up as empty.